# How to know that a table is locked or is being read by someone else when accessing it using JDBC connection?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I tried inserting a row via JDBC connection in mysql database. Sometime I am unable to write them in the database reason being the same table was being read by some other program. I didn't get any exceptions regarding the failure of query. So how can I know the successful execution of query ???

Comment: So, the insert never reflected in the table, and no error was thrown? Can you post the code and give an example of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing your INSERT in a transaction with proper isolation set.  Let the driver handle this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using `preparedstatement`
So you may be using `pt.executeUpdate()` for inserting where `pt` is object of `PreparedStatement`
Now check `if(pt.executeQuery()>0)`
if true then inserted successfully else not

```
if(pt.executeQuery()>0)
{
System.out.println("inserted");
}
else
{
System.out.println("not inserted");
}
```